# how to write javascript code in <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable soucreID and let us say

```
sourceID = 10;
```

sourceID is dynamic value and always changes so i want to pass this to following  tag

```
<a href="edit-source.php?source=<script>document.write(sourceID)</script>">Edit</a>
```

But its not working,

Can any one tell me how can i write javascript value in `<a href="">` tag.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Code: <div id="popuppage" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" style="max-width:250px;">
ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="d" data-theme="c" style="min-width:210px;">              <li data-icon="gear" class="cust-popuplist" id="popupSourceID">
                        <a href="edit-source.php?source=">Edit</a>
                        <input type="hidden" name="srcvalue" id="srcvalue" value="">
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
             </div>

Comment: basically its a popup box and onclick it opens and i am passing souce ID with this popup and i am assigning ID to srcvalue input field through javascript but not able to gte that value in hyperlink tag?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you could do this:

```
<a href="edit-source.php" class="edit-btn">Edit</a>
```

```js
var id = 10;
var href = $(".edit-btn").prop("href");
$(".edit-btn").prop("href", href + "?source=" + id);
```

I assume you don't know the `id` before the code is rendered, otherwise this is rather moot.

Comment: moot: Subject to debate, dispute, or uncertainty, and typically not admitting of a final decision

Answer (score 1):

In Plain JS you can do

```
<script>
var souceID="somesource"; // this is of course assumed
document.write('<a href="edit-source.php?source='+sourceID+'">Edit</a>')
</script>
```

OR

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.href='edit-source.php?source='+sourceID">Edit</a>
```

Using this code from a comment by the OP:

```
<div id="popuppage" data-role="popup" data-overlay-theme="a" style="max-width:250px;">    
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="d" data-theme="c" style="min-width:210px;"> 
    <li data-icon="gear" class="cust-popuplist" id="popupSourceID"> 
       <a href="#"
       onclick="
         this.href='edit-source.php?source='+
           encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('srcvalue').value);
       ">Edit</a> 
       <input type="hidden" name="srcvalue" id="srcvalue" value="somevalue"> 
    </li> 
   </ul> 
</div>
```

Or how about this: No JS needed at all

```
<form action="edit-source.php">
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="<?php echo $srcvalue; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, your code does not work, i have posted code above, can you check it please

Answer (score 0):

You can't put tags inside of attribute values.

This is an ugly solution.  And also that will work by dumping the variable out when the page first loads.  If you had the variable then then you could just use PHP to insert it.

I'm guessing you want to respond to user input so the variable should be added to the link then.  You need an entirely different approach in which you set the entire href attribute at the proper time.